# Shaders create curved texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I want create rectangle which will be in semicircle form and when I add texture to this form, it will have curved texture. I create simple rectangle, it looks like image below(right it form if we look from a height):
 [image]

And via vertex shader I tried to curve this shape. I tried create this shape
[image]

And I used this vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vTexCoordinate;
uniform mat4 u_MVP;
uniform mat4 textureTransform;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
void main() {
    v_TexCoordinate = (textureTransform * vTexCoordinate).xy;
    vec4 try = vPosition; 
    if(try.x > 0.0  ){
       try[2] =  try.x - 100.0;
    } else {
       try[2] = 100.0 - try.x ;
    }
    gl_Position = u_MVP * try;
}
```

But I didn't see any changes in Z coordinate and didn't see any angle in shape. Can someone say what I do wrong?

Comment: YOur approach doesn't make sense. The vertex shaders operates on vertices. A triangle will always stay flat in a plane, no matter how you move the vertices. And in your case, you just have x=-100 or x=100, so your z coordinte will always be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the role of vertex shaders in the rendering pipeline. As the name suggests, the vertex shader is executed **once for each input vertex**. In your case, you have 4 vertices defining your quad, so the vertex shader will be executed only 4 times. Or maybe 6 times, if you specify the vertices shared by the two triangles twice.

The output values of the vertex shader (`varying` variables) are then interpolated across the triangles, and those interpolated values become the matching inputs to the fragment shader.

If you want to deform your geometry in the vertex shader, the most direct approach is that you specify more vertices. You can subdivide the quad into a grid of vertices. A 3x3 subdivision would looks something like this:

```
 ___________
|\  |\  |\  |
| \ | \ | \ |
|__\|__\|__\|
|\  |\  |\  |
| \ | \ | \ |
|__\|__\|__\|
|\  |\  |\  |
| \ | \ | \ |
|__\|__\|__\|
```

This is just for illustration, in reality you will most likely need a much finer subdivision depending on the curvature you're trying to achieve, and how large the final rendering is.

Calculating the vertex coordinates for this is trivial. They are just fractions of the entire quad range, with all of them being in the same plane.

With relatively recent versions of desktop OpenGL you could use a tessellation shader to generate the interior vertices, while still only specifying the 4 original vertices. But tessellation shaders are only available as an extension in OpenGL ES, and not widely supported yet.

If I understand your drawing correctly, I think there's also a small error in your calculation. I believe it should be this:

```
if(try.x > 0.0  ) {
   try[2] =  try.x - 100.0;
} else {
   try[2] = -try.x - 100.0;
}
```

Or easier:

```
try[2] = abs(try.x) - 100.0;
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I was wrong. I'll try to add one more vertex in center and will change it by z-coordinate